# Удаление элемента из массива, Java

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

Привет! Занимаюсь на данный момент по книге «Структуры данных и алгоритмы в Java» Роберт Лафоре. Там есть пример по удалению элемента из массива по заданному значению. (стр.54)

Выглядит он следующим образом:

```
public class ArrayApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long[] arr;          //ссылка на массив
    arr = new long[100]; //создание массива
    int nElems = 0;      //количество элементов
    int j;               //счетчик цикла
    long searchKey;      //ключи искомого элемента

    // вставка 10 элементов
    arr[0] = 77;
    arr[1] = 99;
    arr[2] = 44;
    arr[3] = 55;
    arr[4] = 22;
    arr[5] = 88;
    arr[6] = 11;
    arr[7] = 00;
    arr[8] = 66;
    arr[9] = 33;
    nElems = 10; //массив содержит 10 элементов

    // вывод элементов
    for (j = 0; j < nElems; j++)
        System.out.print(arr[j] + " ");
    System.out.println("");

    searchKey = 55;                      //удаление элемента с ключом  55
    for (j = 55; j < nElems; j++)        //поиск удаляемого элемента
        if (arr[j] == searchKey)
            break;
    for (int k = j; k < nElems - 1; k++) //сдвиг последующих элементов
        arr[k] = arr[k + 1];
    nElems--;                            //уменьшение размера

    for (j = 0; j < nElems; j++)         //вывод элементов
        System.out.print(arr[j] + " ");
    System.out.println("");
}
}
```

В идеале ответ должен получиться таким:

77 99 44 55 22 88 11 0 66 33

77 99 44 22 88 11 0 66 33

По факту программа работает сейчас так:

77 99 44 55 22 88 11 0 66 33

77 99 44 55 22 88 11 0 66

То есть просто удаляет последний элемент массива вместо заданного значения.

Как все-таки должен быть написать цикл, чтобы она работала корректно?

Comment: А если нужно несколько одинаковых элементов выбросить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавленные/измененные знаки выделил двумя звездочками. Код рабочий

```
public class ArrayApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        long[] arr;          //ссылка на массив
        arr = new long[100]; //создание массива
        int nElems = 0;      //количество элементов
        int j;               //счетчик цикла
        long searchKey;      //ключи искомого элемента

        // вставка 10 элементов
        arr[0] = 77;
        arr[1] = 99;
        arr[2] = 44;
        arr[3] = 55;
        arr[4] = 22;
        arr[5] = 88;
        arr[6] = 11;
        arr[7] = 00;
        arr[8] = 66;
        arr[9] = 33;
        nElems = 10; //массив содержит 10 элементов

        // вывод элементов
        for (j = 0; j < nElems; j++)
            System.out.print(arr[j] + " ");
        System.out.println("");

        searchKey = 55;                      //удаление элемента с ключом  55
        for (j = **0**; j < nElems; j++)    **{** //поиск удаляемого элемента
            if (arr[j] == searchKey)
                break;
                **}**
        for (int k = j; k < nElems - 1; k++) //сдвиг последующих элементов
            arr[k] = arr[k + 1];
        nElems--;                            //уменьшение размера

        for (j = 0; j < nElems; j++)         //вывод элементов
            System.out.print(arr[j] + " ");
        System.out.println("");

}
```

Comment: да, я теперь поняла. спасибо, Сергей :)

Answer (score 0):

Как-то встретил тоже такую проблему, я решил её так.

```
 // The method removes a element[index].
public void remove (int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
       int[] array2 = new int[array.length-1];
        System.arraycopy(array, 1, array2, 0, array2.length);
        array = array2;
    }
    else if (index == array.length-1) {
        int[] array2 = new int[array.length-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
            array2[i] = array[i];
        }
        array = array2;
    }
    else {
        int[] array2 = new int[array.length-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (i > index) {
                array2[i-1] = array[i];
            }
            if (i == index) {
                continue;
            }
            if (i < index) {
                array2[i] = array[i];
            }
        }
        array = array2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] removeItem(int[] numbers, int index){
    for (int i = index; i < numbers.length -1; i++) {
        numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf(numbers, numbers.length - 1);
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]